# can't connect mysql local server while deploy to aws

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy django rest app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I followed [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#comment-2849390172) tutorial and I configure DATABASES in setting.py like following

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
            'USER': 'USER_NAME',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
```

and I add following code to .ebextensions directory,

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myApp.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "./src"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: [WSGI_PATH]
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "www/static/"

container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python campusBackend/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

However, when I try to deploy, it gives me the error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)").
>   container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/02_python.config failed.

I really stucked at this point and I have no idea how to solve this.

EDIT: I am using the following inbound/outbound rules for RDS

[image]

Comment: Are you using RDS for database? How is your Security Group setup?

Comment: @filipebarretto I added the security group that used please check it

Comment: the information we need is actually the rules from the second security group on the list: Security Group for RDS DB

Comment: @filipebarretto I added them :)

Comment: Ok. So what that is saying is that only environments in the sg-9e8e91e7 security group can access your database. Can you make sure the EC2s Beanstalk is creating are with the correct security group?

Comment: On your IF statement, why didn't you define the env variables on ELSE?

Comment: @filipebarretto what do you mean by env variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130744/discussion-between-can-and-filipebarretto).